# tmux running in docker creates an error

Tags: dockerfile, tmux

I have a script that uses tmux which runs fine on my base machine.

When I run the same script in a docker image, I get the following error:

```
failed to connect to server: Connection refused
```

I am gonna reboot and see if this problem goes away. Tackle again tomorrow.

My confidence in tmux is flagging... :^)

Comment: No one can help you if you show no code or something. I guest I can only whish you luck tomorrow.

Comment: So I needed to write some support scripts for this project, and I tested them with an Ubuntu docker container, still get the same error.

Comment: I went to supply some sample code after leaving the Ubuntu based system on through the July 4th weekend, and now the system loads and executes tmux code normally.  I am guessing that It is as if the sockets on the main system has quiesced and so the guest system can access the sockets.  I will see if I can get the problem to reproduce, and when I do I will publish a simple code test.

Answer (score -1):

This is a false alarm.  The initial code in the first terminal was failing and I did not notice it.  A terrible bug and I am afraid a less than competent programmer.

The wonderful tmux works fine under docker.

Regards,

Flint